# Erro Ao fazer Upload com o Bootstrap fileinput

Tags: java, spring, upload, plugin, http-request

Bem estou tendo problemas com esse plugin gostaria de saber se alguém já mexeu com ele e se poderia ajudar na questão

estou com problemas de comunicação com o controller estou tomando o seguinte erro 405 Method Not Allowed, porem só no momento da utilização desse plugin as demais funções do meu sistema como cadastro consulta estao ok

segue meu controller que recebe a requisição

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carregarupload", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody Object upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("upload() called");

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        request.setAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
        return "uploadStatus";
    }

    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        request.setAttribute("message", "You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getSuccessMessage().toString();
}

private JSONObject getSuccessMessage() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"success\":true}");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

e também segue a pagina que faz a requisição do post junto com o script do plugin

```
<div class="containerK">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="${methodName}"
        action="${action}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="file-1" name="file" type="file" multiple class="file"
                data-overwrite-initial="false" data-min-file-count="1">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#file-1").fileinput({
            uploadUrl : '/upload', // you must set a valid URL here else you will get an error
            allowedFileExtensions : [ 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'war' ],
            overwriteInitial : false,
            maxFileSize : 10000,
            maxFilesNum : 10,
            //allowedFileTypes: ['image', 'video', 'flash'],
            slugCallback : function(filename) {
                return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
            }
        });
    });
```

se alguém poder ajudar fico grato

este e controlador do metodo upload

```
@RequestMapping(value = REDIRECT_PAGE_UPLOAD, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView showUpload(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    model.addAttribute(ControllerConstants.METHOD_NAME, RequestMethod.POST.name());

    model.addAttribute(MODEL_NAME, new ItoBean(false));

    model.addAttribute(HABILITAR_CAMPOS, true);

    model.addAttribute(ControllerConstants.METHOD_NAME, RequestMethod.POST.name());

    String action = String.join(SEPARATOR, request.getContextPath(), ACTION_UPLOAD);

    model.addAttribute(ControllerConstants.ACTION, action);


    return new ModelAndView(REQUEST_MAPPING_PAGE_UPLOAD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O Erro 405 indica que o serviço (POST) não suporta o método que está sendo invocado. Em seu formulário você usou uma variável (${methodName}) para o tipo do método, é bem provável que ele não está sendo preenchida, e o action pode estar com o mesmo problema. Tente modificar o seu formulário assim:

```
    <body>
    <div class="containerK">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/carregarupload">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="file-1" name="file" type="file" multiple data-min-file-count="0" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#file-1").fileinput();
      });
    </script>
</body>

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UploadController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/carregarupload", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
  public @ResponseBody String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
      byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
      Path path = Paths.get("/home/guilherme/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
      Files.write(path, bytes);
      request.setAttribute("message", "You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "{\"success\":true}";
  }

}
```

Comment: opa então cara tentei deixar da forma que você  indicou porem o erro continua

Comment: @WesleySantos o erro (405 Method Not Allowed) continua? Testei o seu código não utilizando o fileInput do jQuery mas com um botão de submit no formulário e funcionou normalmente, outra dúvida: Como está mapeado o RequestMapping do Controlador onde está o método **upload**

Comment: então o erro persiste vou editar e colocar o resto do meu controller para que vc entenda todo o contexto

Comment: então se poder me mandar o exemplo que você criou em cima do meu código para que eu posso testar

Comment: @WesleySantos com essas variáveis no seu código não tem como eu entender como está sendo montado os contextos, tenta validar se o path e o métodos estão batendo, pois a sua implementação está correta

Comment: cara tentei implementar

Comment: mais mesmo assim continuo tomando o erro 405